# Can I use debugger in Java code before printing to the console and understand values?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

The IntelliJ IDEA program has a debugging option, but I don't know if I can check the intermediate values of the variables through it. For example, in the code, when I put a breakpoint, I don't know how I could add the input values to see the intermediate values.

Comment: Might want to add intellij-idea to your tags.

Comment: Yes, the debugger will allow you to run your program, one line at a time, giving you as much time as you like to inspect things before letting the program run again. Learning how to use a debugger is very useful, well worth the time.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can debug your code and step through it to better understand what is happening. In essence, you would set a breakpoint at a location of your interest, then tell IntelliJ to run your program in debug mode (breakpoints enabled). How to do this exactly can be seen from various fine resources:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/intellij_idea/intellij_idea_debugging.htm
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/05/debugger-basics-in-intellij-idea/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to **[set the variable values](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html#setting-variable-values)** through the debugger, - yes, you can use **Set** from the context menu of the variable:

Set variable values﻿
If there is a need to test how the program would behave in certain conditions or fix its current behavior at runtime, you can do that by setting/changing the variable values.

1. Right-click a variable on the Variables tab and select Set value, or select the variable and press F2.
2. Enter the value for the variable and press ⏎.

[image: Enter new value for the variable in the field right next to its name]